# Issue in defining one to many mapping from one entity to another

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jakarta-ee

Suppose I have 2 tables T1 and T2.

```
t1id is Primary Key (PK) in table T1 .   
T1 references T2 via t2id    which is Foreign Key(FK)
T1 to T2 is one to many relationship

Schemas : 
--------------------------------------------------------

T1 ( t1id (PK) , name , t2id(FK))
T2 ( t2id(PK) , author)

-------------------------------------------------------
```

Can somebody help me with defining the enity classes for the requirements above?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your entity class like as below below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T1")
public class T1Entity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="t1id")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "t1_seq", sequenceName = "t1_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "t1_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long t1id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = T2Entity.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "t2id", referencedColumnName = "t2id")
private T2Entity t2;


//getter and setter    
}
```

And your T2 Entity can be written as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T2")
public class T2Entity implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="t2id")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "t2_seq", sequenceName = "t2_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "t2_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long t2id;

//other columns

//getter and setter    
}
```

Comment: If you want you can add bi-directional relationship between t1 and t2 entities. do let me know if you need such relationship.